# How can I prevent Pinterest save button from 'hiding' under a div?

Tags: javascript, html, button, hidden, pinterest

I have added a Pinterest 'save' button to my page.  But the script places the Pinterest button on top of a transparent div.  This prevents the user from being able to click the button without first scrolling down the page. How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks, everyone.

Update, next day. Found a solution!  Add the following code to the div that is preventing the button click from working:   style="pointer-events: none;"

Please see http://waterfallsofontario.com/c/intro8pin.php

Please see the [Pinterest button at top of the page.](http://waterfallsofontario.com/c/intro8pin.php)
 Scroll down to make it work.

Comment: manually create the button and set the href to it. This is the DOM for the button `<span class="PIN_1529985021164_button_pin PIN_1529985021164_save" data-pin-log="button_pinit_floating" data-pin-href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?guid=AHDoJa6SzF6w&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwaterfallsofontario.com%2Fc%2Fintro8pin.php&amp;media=http%3A%2F%2Fwaterfallsofontario.com%2Fc%2Finventory_splash_algoma.jpg&amp;description=Waterfalls%20of%20Ontario2%3A%20Algoma%20Region%20Waterfall%20Inventory" style="position: absolute; top: 109px; left: 161px; z-index: 8675309;">Save</span>`

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Found a solution.  One of my divs was "covering" the button.  It was a 50% transparent div containing a title that shows over top of the image.  This prevented the button from being clickable until you scroll down. The solution is to add the following code to the div in question:  style="pointer-events: none;"